# Unable to read and write serial data between two arduino's (hc-05 paired) when using a sensor

Tags: serial, bluetooth, softwareserial, hc-05

What I did was that I wrote a piece of code that will-in-fact move a servo motor when a clap is detected using a sound impact sensor (fc-04). 
The code for this is seen here and in fact does work:

```
#include "Arduino.h"                                                            
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;//create servo object to control a servo                                                                                  
enum {                                                                          
    SERIAL_BAUD        = 9600,                                                  
    SENSOR_DIGITAL_PIN =    2,                                                  
    SOUND_DELAY        =   1500, /* Delay to avoid duplicate detection */         
};                                                                              

void setup() {                                                                  
    Serial.begin(SERIAL_BAUD);                                                  
    pinMode(SERIAL_BAUD, INPUT);
    myservo.attach(9);//attachs the servo on pin 9 to servo object
    myservo.write(0);//back to 0 degrees 
    delay(1000);//wait for a second                                                
}                                                                               

void loop() {                                                                   
    if (digitalRead(SENSOR_DIGITAL_PIN) == LOW) {                               
        static int count;                                                       

        Serial.print("Sound detected: ");                                       
        Serial.println(++count);    
        myservo.write(170);//goes to 15 degrees 
        delay(3000);//wait for 3 seconds
        myservo.write(10);//back to 0 degrees 
        delay(1000);//wait for a second                                                            

        // Wait a short bit to avoid multiple detection of the same sound.      
        delay(SOUND_DELAY);                                                     
    }                                                                           
}
```

On a seperate occasion I paired two arduinos together using two hc-05 bluetooth modeules making one a slave and another a master, the initial code I used for both of them are listed here:

```
//                 == SLAVE CODE ==


#include <Servo.h>
#define button 8

Servo myServo;
int state = 20;
int buttonState = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
  myServo.attach(9);
  Serial.begin(38400); // Default communication rate of the Bluetooth module
}

void loop() {
 if(Serial.available() > 0){ // Checks whether data is comming from the serial port
    state = Serial.read(); // Reads the data from the serial port
 }
 // Controlling the servo motor
 myServo.write(state);
 delay(10);

 // Reading the button
 buttonState = digitalRead(button);
 if (buttonState == HIGH) {
   Serial.write('1'); // Sends '1' to the master to turn on LED
 }
 else {
   Serial.write('0');
 }  
}
```

and

```
//                == MASTER CODE ==

#define ledPin 9

int state = 0;
int potValue = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  Serial.begin(38400); // Default communication rate of the Bluetooth module
}

void loop() {
 if(Serial.available() > 0){ // Checks whether data is comming from the serial port
    state = Serial.read(); // Reads the data from the serial port
 }
 // Controlling the LED
 if (state == '1') {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // LED ON
  state = 0;
 }
 else if (state == '0') {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // LED ON
  state = 0;
 }
 // Reading the potentiometer
 potValue = analogRead(A0);
 int potValueMapped = map(potValue, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
 Serial.write(potValueMapped); // Sends potValue to servo motor
 delay(10);
}
```

I attempted to use the master and slave code with the one with the servo and fc-04 so that the sound sensor will be on the master and the servo on the slave so that when ever I clap it will move the servo on the other arduino.

The new master and slave code that I used are :

```
//New slave
#include "Arduino.h"                                                            
#include <Servo.h>
int state = 0;
Servo myservo;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(38400); // Default communication rate of the Bluetooth module
  myservo.attach(9);//attachs the servo on pin 9 to servo object
  myservo.write(0);//back to 0 degrees 
  delay(1000);//wait for a second 
  }


void loop() {
 if(Serial.available() > 0){ // Checks whether data is comming from the serial port
    state = Serial.read(); // Reads the data from the serial port
 }
// Controlling the servo
 if (state == '1') {
  myservo.write(170);//goes to 15 degrees 
  delay(3000);//wait for 3 seconds
  myservo.write(10);//back to 0 degrees 
  delay(1000);//wait for a second
  state = 0;
 }
 else if (state == '0') {
  state = 0;
  }  
}

//new Master 
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
int state = 0;
SoftwareSerial BTserial(1, 0); // RX | TX                       

void setup() {                                                                  
    Serial.begin(9600);                                                  
    pinMode(9600, INPUT);
    BTserial.begin(38400);

}

void loop() {                                                                   
    if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) {                               
        static int count; 
        BTserial.write('1');
        delay(1500);
    }
    else {
      BTserial.write('0');
    }
}
```

However the slave and master code for the servo and fc-04 is not working at all despite knowing that all the conponents work individually. What I am aware of is that the fc-04 uses serial communication to transfer data and so does the hc-05 bluetooth modules. This causes an issue because I believe from experience is that you can not have two serial communications being transmitted from the arduino at the same time which I need.
I have been at this for days and It is driving me nuts.
If I could have some help at all I will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> SoftwareSerial BTserial(1, 0); // RX | TX

Well, there's your problem.  You are starting `SoftwareSerial` on the `Serial` pins.  Don't do that!

For best results, hook your BT to pins 8 & 9 and use [AltSoftSerial](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/AltSoftSerial).  It is *much* more efficient than `SoftwareSerial`, and it will not interfere with `Serial` reads and writes.

If you really can't use those pins, pick two other pins and use my [NeoSWSerial](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoSWSerial).  It is almost as efficient, and it works on any PinChange interrupt pins at 9600, 19200 or 38400 baud rates.

Comment: Gotcha , so because of what I was doing it causes crosstalk then.
When I have the chance tomorrow I will make the required changes and report back on the results.
Thanks